# agregar un alias al resultado de WITH ROLLUP

Tags: mysql

[image: consulta mysql][image: resultado que obtengo]
buenas tardes amigos de Stackoverflow,  tengo una tabla llamada paciente, en la cual tengo un campo llamado edad donde registro edad de los pacientes, yo realizo una consulta donde agrupo por rango de edades y cuento la cantidad de pacientes en cada rango, hago uso de la funcion WITH ROLLUP para contar el total, hasta ahi todo bien, mi pregunta es: ¿Hay alguna manera de que en vez de que aparezca NULL me muestre que diga total?

Comment: Por favor amigo edita y agrega tu consulta como texto y no como imagen, considera leer [ask]

Comment: Un comentario que igual te va bien, siempre es mejor guardar la fecha de nacimiento y no la edad, ya que las personas cada año, cambian de edad.

Comment: en mo tabla tengo un campo de fecha de nacimiento y uno de edad, lo que sucede es que yo selecciono en un formulario la fecha de nacimiento en un calendario y en un input de manera automatica me muestra la edad, y yo guardo en mi tabla la fecha de nacimiento y la edad

Answer (score 0):

Usa la sentencia `IF GROUPING` de este modo:

**EJEMPLO**

- Yo sumo la cantidad que hay por cada país
- Dentro del condicional indico que si estoy agrupando por el país entonces agregue un alias
- Paso como tercer argumento la columna por la cual estoy agrupando
- Finalmente le doy un alias a la columna generada

Código:

```
SELECT IF(GROUPING(pais), 'Gran Total', pais) AS pais,
       SUM(total) AS T
FROM demo
GROUP BY pais
WITH ROLLUP;
```

Entonces:

> En tu código deberías meter dentro del condicional la columna por la cual agrupas que es **`rango`**

Obtendrías un resultado como el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Referencia**

- [WITH ROLLUP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html)

Comment: ok probare a ver que tal funciona

Comment: GROUPING no me reconoce como valido en mysql

Comment: @edwin ¿qué versión de mysql tienes?

Comment: 4.8.5 esa es la version que estoy usando de mysql y la version del servidor es 5.7.26

Comment: Vaya si que usas una versión no solo antigua si no que además obsoleta considerando que vamos en la 8.X.X, bueno considera que si puedes actualizar tu MySQL esta sería la solución @edwin

Answer (score 0):

Puedes simplemente, en caso que la columna sea `NULL` reemplazar este valor por la cadena de total. Aquí un ejemplo reproducible:

```
select ifnull(table_type, 'Totales') as Tipo, 
       count(1) 
       FROM information_schema.TABLES
       group by table_type with rollup
```

Esto sirve por que en tu caso `contar_edad` no tiene posibilidad que sea `NULL`